# Make a buttom that saves my picture, in a folder that gets its name from a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a program for the car retail firm I work at. When people deliver their cars, a guy has to take pictures of the damages with a Lenovo miix.

The program I've made so far is not smart enough.
It goes like, you write the numberplate in a box, then create a folder with the text from the box.

Then you start the camera, take a picture and save it, and manually have to find the folder and name the file.

[image: pic of program]
Is there a way I can make it smarter with just 2 buttons, one to start the camera and another one to take the picture, and then it automatically saves it in a folder named as the numberplate, and files named 1,2,3,4 and so on.jpg ?

this is my code so far:

```
namespace Europcar_skade_camera
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private FilterInfoCollection webcam;
        private VideoCaptureDevice cam;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach(FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in webcam)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(webcam[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Cam_NewFrame);
            cam.Start();
        }

        private void Cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bit = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pictureBox1.Image = bit;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cam.IsRunning)
            {
                cam.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\tmp\";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void nummerplade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\tmp\" + nummerplade.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you write the reg plate in the box, cant you just use that text as the file name?

Comment: Your button4_Click event is building a directory structure for you, amend this to also save away the path as a local variable in your app, this way you have easy access to the folder.

Comment: to automatically number your images, on picture take increment a number and assign to the image, the more times you take a picture the higher the number gets until you clear by closing the app for changing the number plate

Comment: @uk2k05 what if he accidentally closes app while still hadn't finished taking all pictures of car? increments then should be saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Instead of using a SaveFileDialog, you could just create the file path based on the number plate value like this:

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\tmp", nummerplade.Text, fileNumber + ".jpeg");
```

The `fileNumber` var is the number of files allready in the folder + 1.

`var fileNumber = Directory.GetFiles(...).Length + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
string numberPlate = "21323412";
string path = @"C:\tmp\";

Directory.CreateDirectory(path + numberPlate); //to create folder
string dirpath = path + numberPlate; //to get name of fodler we created
```

You also mentioned that you want incremental names, there are many ways of doing it, personally i'd prefer large hashed name of file like so:

```
//generate GUID and convert to string.
string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

//to save picturebox image in folder and use ImageFormat.Your desired format
pictureBox1.Image.Save(dirpath + @"\"+filename+".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

But if you want to stick with incremental names:

```
// you get last name in the folder:

//it gets last filename in folder but with path
var lastFilePath = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First(); 

//we remove path from filename and convert it to int.
int lastIndex = Int32.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lastFilePath)); 

//then we increment it by 1
int newName = lastIndex + 1;

//and save it
pictureBox1.Image.Save(dirpath + @"\"+filename+".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);  //to save picturebox image in folder
```

**With GUID finally it should look something like this:**

```
    string numberPlate = "21323412";
    string path = @"C:\tmp\";

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path + numberPlate); //to create folder
        string dirpath = path + numberPlate; //to get name of fodler we created
        string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(dirpath + @"\"+filename+".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); //to save picturebox image in folder

    }
```

Comment: @Peter I made some changes in my answer, if you will have any other errors just tell me.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me :) !..
Now i get a error : The name 'ImageFormat' Does not exist in the currect context [link](http://oi65.tinypic.com/1676pvc.jpg)

Comment: yes because you need to add **using System.Drawing.Imaging;** in the top of the file :)

Comment: thanks @Nick :). i get error when hitting the button now.
[link](http://oi65.tinypic.com/2mqvjhf.jpg)

Comment: @Peter you forgot to change "Path" that i used for example :D you should use your path, where your folder will be. for example: c:\myfolder\itWillspawnHere

Comment: yeah sorry i had tried that. ill show a picture :). it shows a error with invalid signs in the path. (translated) [link](http://oi63.tinypic.com/2afmw07.jpg)

Comment: @Peter it is not problem if you have any other questions, if not and i solved your problem please accept my answer :)